# Executing pyqt files through ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, pyqt5

I am trying to execute a python file coded for Graphical user Interface using pyqt modules using ssh. It gives me a message 
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:10.0

I tried several ways checking for the x11 forwarding etc etc.Nothing seems to work. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` by default does not forward the X session, so your program on will try to open its window on the remote host (where it will be rejected in most cases because the X server on the remote host is either not running at all (e. g. if it is a headless server) or because it isn't configured to display the stuff.  And even if it would accept the window of your application, it would display it on the remote host's display, not on your local one.  So that wouldn't be what you want either.

Try `ssh -X …` when starting your application via `ssh`.  This will tell `ssh` to forward the X session so that your application on the remote host will send its window back to the X server running on your local machine which it will be accepted and displayed.

Comment: Can you be ,ore precise about the ssh command please since i do not know ssh very well and i am using raspberry pi as my remote host             Thanks a lot

Comment: And also after i log in into the host if i use sudo python file.py it shows this error . If i use just python file.py it opens Interface but communication is not happening.

Comment: If your `ssh` connection is interactive, just add the option `-X` to your existing `ssh` call.  Anything you do after that which is supposed to open a window will then send that window through the `ssh` connection to your local window server.  So:  `ssh -X` and then `sudo file.py`.

Comment: You might want to consider using ssh-keys for logging in as `root` directly.  Then the `sudo` isn't necessary anymore.  For this, add the contents of your local file `~/.ssh.id_rsa.pub` to the remote file `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, then you can just do `ssh -X root@raspi /path/to/file.py`.

Comment: oh yes Thank you i tried the above one,but it still shows me the same error